# Return value after successful assert

Tags: java, junit

I have a little problem with a function used for testing. Here is my test method:

```
public static List<FieldError> proofFields(final List<String> fieldNames, final List<FieldError> errors, boolean fieldsAbsent){
    List<FieldError> foundFields = errors.stream().filter(fieldError -> fieldNames.contains(fieldError.getField())).collect(toList());
    if(fieldsAbsent){
        assertTrue(foundFields.isEmpty());
    } else {
        assertTrue(fieldNames.size() == foundFields.size());
    }
    return foundFields;
}
```

It should check, if one list is (partially) contained in the other.

I would like to return the result, no matter if the test was successful or not. Is there a way to do this or does assertTrue/assertFalse always exit immediately?

Comment: Your code should work fine.

Comment: Asserts throw an exception if the conditions are not met. If you don't want that, maybe you want to print a message instead of using asserts.

Comment: you can just catch AssertionError and do nothing with it

Comment: Why do you want to ignore the result of assertTrue if it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your method should return value or verify data.Don't mix it. You did it and now you have a problem :)

```
public static List<FieldError> proofFields(final List<String> fieldNames, final 
       List<FieldError> errors){
         return errors.stream().filter(fieldError -> 
       fieldNames.contains(fieldError.getField())).collect(toList());
}

public static assertFieldWithError(final List<String> fieldNames, final 
       List<FieldError> errors){
      assertEquals(fieldNames.size(), foundFields.isEmpty());
      ... iterate do more detail and check ....with assertXXXX();
}

public static assertFieldWithoutError(final 
       List<FieldError> errors){
      assertTrue(foundFields.isEmpty());
}
```

also for construction like :

```
assertTrue(fieldNames.size() == foundFields.size())
```

better use

```
assertEquals(fieldsAbsent.size() , foundFields.size());
```

as it more informative way.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice way to combine it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have it both ways. You can't have your cake *and* eat it.

Either you are using one of the many JUnit 'asserts` - or you have code that doesn't throw exceptions.

Meaning: it is the nature of `assert()` to throw when its condition is not met.

Thus the answer: *you* have to get *clear* on your requirements. If you want that test to throw in certain situations, then keep the `asserts` in. If you want to return results always, then you remove those calls.